# Kotlin async/await syntax without blocking caller

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'd like to figure out if Kotlin can replace our current way of dealing with asynchronous code. Right now, we use `CompletableFutures` to handle asynchronous code. Here is an example of a such a method:

```
public void onBalanceRequest(Client client, String name) {
  db.fetchBalance(name)
    .thenAccept(balance -> {
       client.sendMessage("Your money: " + balance);
    });
}
```

The important point here is that `onBalanceRequest` is called from the main thread, that must not be blocked. Internally, `db.fetchBalance` runs asynchronous operations and resolves the future on completion, so the given call is not blocking the main thread.

After reviewing the Kotlin docs regarding coroutines, I had hope that we can do something like JavaScript's async/await. For example, this is what we can do in JavaScript:

```
async function onBalanceRequest(client, name) {
  let balance = await db.fetchBalance(name);
  client.sendMessage("Your money: " + balance);
}
```

Now, I've tried to connect our existing API to a Kotlin project:

```
private fun onBalanceRequest(client: Client) = runBlocking {
    val money = db.fetchBalance(client.name)
    client.sendMessage("Your money: $money")
}

suspend fun fetchBalance(player: String): Double? {
    var result: Double? = null
    GlobalScope.launch {
        originalFetchBalance(player).thenAccept {
            result = it
        }
    }.join()
    return result
}
```

However, since I used `runBlocking`, the execution of `onBalanceRequest` is blocking the main thread. So I'm aksing you, if I can achieve something similar to async/await with Kotlin.

Thank you.

Comment: why do you use `runBlocking` if you didn't want to block in the first place?

Comment: Because I have no idea what I could try instead. That is the question. This was just an example to visualize the "idea".

Comment: `runBlocking` is for blocking code... `launch` is for non-blocking ;-)

Comment: When replacing `runBlocking` with `launch`, my code won't compile. I don't really understand why, but I thought that it can not be used there?

Comment: what do you mean with "won't compile"? are you using Kotlin 1.3?

Comment: Yes, I am. Using GlobalScope.launch is working. Just using `launch` is not resolving.

Answer (score 5):

If your JS function is `async`, the corresponding Kotlin function should be `suspend`:

```
private suspend fun onBalanceRequest(client: Client) {
    val money = db.fetchBalance(client.name)
    client.sendMessage("Your money: $money")
}
```

There's no need for `await`, because Kotlin is statically typed and the compiler already knows which functions are `suspend` and need to be treated specially (though C#, which is also statically typed, uses `async`/`await` model for explicitness).

Note that it can only be called directly from `suspend` functions; if you want to "fire-and-forget" it, use `launch`:

```
private fun onBalanceRequest(client: Client) = GlobalScope.launch {
    val money = db.fetchBalance(client.name)
    client.sendMessage("Your money: $money")
}
```

And for using your `CompletableFuture`-returning functions, use [kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8/):

```
// should be suggested by IDE
import kotlinx.coroutines.future.await

suspend fun fetchBalance(player: String) = originalFetchBalance(player).await()
```

Comment: Thank you. `.await()` doesn't exist here, but `.join()` does and seems to do the job.

Comment: Can we correct / discuss this, so I can mark your answer as the solution?

Comment: Did you add the dependency for kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8?

Comment: No, but do you see any issues with just using `.join()`, since it seems to work without adding additional dependencies?

Comment: If you want to avoid dependencies, you can extract an equivalent to `await()` from tynn's answer, but it will be less efficient than the one in kotlinx.

Comment: For me, it does not block the thread. Everything works as expected. 
The main thread continues running.

Comment: It blocks the thread it's called in, with this code it won't be the main thread.

Comment: If you claim it doesn't block the main thread, then why do you even consider coroutines? You already have all they set out to provide. Just call `future.join()` everywhere and be a happy coder.

Answer (score 2):

Of course `runBlocking` will run blocking. So instead use `launch`.

```
private fun onBalanceRequest(client: Client) = GlobalScope.launch {
    val money = db.fetchBalance(client.name)
    client.sendMessage("Your money: $money")
}
```

To bridge your `CompletableFuture`, you can use `CompletableDeferred` then

```
suspend fun fetchBalance(player: String): Double {
    val async = CompletableDeferred()
    originalFetchBalance(player).whenComplete { (value, error) ->
        if (value != null) async.complete(value)
        if (error != null) async.completeExceptionally(error)
    }
    return async.await()
}
```