# Proper way to make async network request in Kotlin 1.1.0 without extra libraries

Tags: kotlin, minecraft-forge

I'm currently working on a [[minecraft-forge]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-forge) mod, targeting a very old version of their system.

Relevant info:

- Gradle wrapper can be no newer than version 3.0
- Kotlin can be no newer than version 1.1.0
- I can't seem to find versioned documentation on kotlin
- My code is injected into the main program; it doesn't run independently.
- This is not running on android.

I've been trying to figure out how to *properly/idiomatically* create an async network request using pure kotlin, and update items on the main thread when it's completed. The network request shouldn't permanently hang the main program when it's completed.

What I've tried so far:

```
// Player is a custom class of mine that stores data I fetch here
class FetchStatsThread(val uuid: String, val callback: (player: Player) -> Unit): Thread() {
    override fun run() {
        val url = URL("domain")
        val request: URLConnection = url.openConnection()
        request.connect()
        val str = InputStreamReader(request.getContent() as InputStream).buffered().use(BufferedReader::readText)
        // do some stuff here that generates a Player object named playerData
        callback(playerData)
    }
}

...

// Elsewhere, i trigger the request with:
FetchStatsThread(uuid, callback).start()
```

Is this the proper way to make asynchronous network requests in kotlin 1.1 or older?

Comment: Not a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117987/kotlin-async-await-syntax-without-blocking-caller?rq=1,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547947/proper-way-to-thread-in-kotlin?rq=1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219379/how-to-make-an-api-request-in-kotlin?rq=1,  as these questions regard features in Kotlin 1.3 or Kotlin on android

Comment: I think you'd have a better time figuring out how to update your gradle/kotlin version than trying to work around an awfully outdated version of kotlin

Comment: @krit why are you constrained on Gradle and Kotlin version?

Comment: Which JDK version are you targeting? If JDK11+ you have a higher-level `HttpClient` you can use, rather than the old fashioned `URLConnection`